# How to export ftp list from phpdesigner 8?

Tags: ftp, phpdesigner

I've got ftp connections list in phpDesigner.
How to export or to save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can find the ftp xml file in:
C:\Users\your user dir\AppData\Roaming\phpDesigner

phpdesigner_ftp.xml

For Windows XP users (and I assume they still exist in numbers!)... the Path is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[Windows-User]\Application Data\phpDesigner
```

For example, I've Windows User account with the name "Ruturaaj". So, my path looks like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Ruturaaj\Application Data\phpDesigner
```

It's quite handy to know this folder because it contains some other useful XML files as well. For example, look for "autocomplete.xml". This is the file that contains all Auto-Complete code snippets you've added to phpDesigner over a period of time. Now that you know this folder path, I'd suggest to backup this folder and simply overwrite the files with new installation to setup same environment over and over again.